# Ruby File.exist? returns true before file is readable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, delayed-job

I've got a Rails app where I'm trying to pass the creation of a large PDF to a background process and allow the user to see it when it's finished. It's a multi-page document combined with the combine_pdf gem and passed to delayed_job.

I have 3 actions: the first creates and saves the file, the second is called repeatedly with short delays via an asynchronous request to check if the file exists yet, and the third shows the PDF in the browser.

I'm having trouble with the second part, as it uses `File.exist?('my_file.pdf')`, but this is returning `true` before the file has finished saving. The link that is then shown to view the PDF results in an error (ActionController::MissingFile). The file actually becomes available about 10 seconds later, at which point the link works correctly.

I'm guessing the file is still being written at the point that it's checked? How can I check the file saving has completed and the file is actually available to be read?

Comment: Personally I would save some kind of reference to the delayed_job process and check if the job has finished before reading the file, but it's easier to implement some kind of temp file and move/rename it after it's saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is (very broadly and somewhat roughly) how I do it:

First, I call a `post` action on the controller that is calling the background create process. This action creates a `ServiceRequest` (a model in my app) with relevant `service_request.details` and a status of `created`. The `service_request` is then sent to the background process (I use RabbitMQ). And the action returns the `service_request.id`.

The front end starts pinging (via AJAX) the service request end point (something like `service_requests/:id`), and the `ServiceRequestController`'s `show` action sends back the `service_request.status` (along with other stuff, including `service_request.results`. This loops while the `service_request.status` is neither `completed` nor `failed`.

Meanwhile, the background process creates the PDF. When it is done, it sets the `service_request.status` to `completed`. And, it sets `service_request.results` to contain the data the front end needs to locate and retrieve the PDF. (I store my PDFs to and AWS bucket since I'm on Heroku.)

When the front end finally receives a service_request.status of `completed` it uses the `service_request.results` to fetch and display the PDF.

Comment: Or push a notification over Action Cable instead of having the client poll.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I don't do Action Cable (yet), but that seems very true.

Answer (score 1):

You could write to a temp file then rename it once it's finished. You haven't included your code so far but something like this could work for you:

```
def write_and_replace(path, file, file_name, data)
  file_path = File.join(folder_path, "#{file_name}.pdf")
  temp_file_path = File.join(folder_path, "temp_#{file_name}.pdf")

  File.open(temp_file_path, 'w') { |f| f.write(data) }

  # Args: existing file, new name
  File.rename(path, file_path)
  File.rename(temp_file_path, file)
  File.delete(file_path)
end
```